# Surreal DB - Query from Sets

Tags: surrealdb

I have created an author user in surreal DB like this:

```sql
CREATE author:shivam SET
    name.first = 'Shivam',
    name.last = 'Sahil',
    name.full = string::join(' ', name.first, name.last),
    age = 23,
    admin = true,
    signup_at = time::now()
;
```

Now I want to query all the authors, but when I do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM author;
```

I get 0 results.

Is it supposed to be queried in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did should work well as you can see here

[image]

Don't forget to start your server with something like this for example

> `surreal start --log info --user root --pass root memory`

and log-in as in my above screenshot with:

> `surreal sql --conn http://localhost:8000 --ns yoloswag --db compabie`

Then, your create query and select should work well!

---

Alternatively, you can give a try to [that video](https://youtu.be/DPQbuW9dQ7w) or [documentation's quick start](https://surrealdb.com/docs/start).

---

Creating another author like this is properly fetched afterwards.

```sql
CREATE author:123 SET
    name.first = 'bob',
    name.last = 'hoh',
    name.full = string::join(' ', name.first, name.last),
    age = 30,
    admin = false,
    signup_at = time::now()
;
```

Don't forget that `123` is supposed to be a unique ID (a string should be fine tho).